# is there any ways to detect the application is currently in which platform like mobile or web?

Tags: angular, angular6

I have to run my application on web and mobile platform simultaneously. But have to know the platform is mobile or web?. According to which platform is switched, I have to slightly change the code depending on the platform.

if anyone have any different views about this, pls let me know.

Answer (score 0):

https://material.angular.io/cdk/platform/overview
Angular CDK contains this information

Comment: thanks for your reply. this doesn't work for my requirement. but i got "navigator.userAgent" method for detect the device.

Answer (score 0):

```
.is-desktop {
display: block !important;
}

.is-mobile {
display: none !important;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.is-desktop {
display: none !important;
}

.is-mobile {
display: block !important;
}
}
<div class="is-mobile">Code for mobile</div>
<div class="is-desktop">Code for desktop/web</div>
```

And if you want to do it in angular typescript you can do it as

```
import {BreakpointObserver} from '@angular/cdk/layout';
isSmallScreen = false;
constructor(breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {
this.isSmallScreen = breakpointObserver.isMatched('(max-width: 768px)');
}
// and import this in app.module imports array
import {LayoutModule} from '@angular/cdk/layout';
imports:[LayoutModule]
```